# Spring returning HTTP 404 even though URL is mapped

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jax-rs, cxf

When i access the url http://localhost:8080/test/testSpring, my spring boot app returned 404 error even though I have mapped the URL in my controller.

My REST service:

```
@RestController
public class TestSpring {
  @RequestMapping(value="/test/testSpring", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String test() {
    return "test ok";
  }
}
```

Console log shows URL is mapped:

```
RequestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/test/testSpring],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String ...
```

Comment: do you have context path property in application.properties? also attach screenshot of directory structure of project.

Comment: Try to request it with explicit `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`

Comment: Are you accessing the application directly or via a reverse proxy like NGINX or Apache? Sometimes, if these are being matched in a location match (in NGINX terminology) which has a path prefix then the proxy request might contain the prefix, meaning that the actual request being asked is something like `/something/test/testSpring`

Comment: @DavidGoate, I'm accessing through localhost and using the default spring-boot embedded tomcat so I doubt there's any kind of proxy.

Comment: ok thanks, yes in that case I doubt it too. It might be useful to share the output of `curl -v http://localhost:8080/test/testSpring` and any relevant logs that occur on the server.

Comment: Do you use any server.servlet.context-path ? and could you show us the console ?

Comment: From the startup logs, can you check where dispatcherServlet is getting mapped ? Ideally it should be to "/" if not then prefix the dispatcherServlet mapping value before "/test/testSpring" and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved the issue by using different url pattern for the jax-rs and spring servlets in my web.xml